# Android volley - how to fetch fresh data?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm struggling with volley library because is not well documented. I'm making multiple http get request to the server, downloading and caching data just fine with standard code found on Google and stackoverflow.

As I understood, when I make a request call to  e.g. www.data.com/users/firstuser It downloads data and cache it on disk. When I make the same call again on that same URL, it will check the cache, won't even connect to the internet and just deliver it to me from the cache. Now I know that the data has changed on that same URL and I need it downloaded, but how can I get fresh data from that same URL and not from the disk cache?

Comment: I use this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/ as my reference and it works perfectly

Comment: You mean you invalidate the cache and download new data?

Comment: it would be easy to recognize if your code is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All volley requests are defaultly cached.For not caching volley request you have to set  `setShouldCache`  to `false` . Have a look at this answer for clear under standing

[Are Android Volley Requests Automatically Cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883329/are-android-volley-requests-automatically-cached)